# T-SQL recursive in order to find transactions for a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, recursion

I have tried but i am not able to figure this out. I have a table transactions (transaction_ID, transaction_Person_ID, Transaction_Date etc).
 What i want is to return all the transaction_person_ID's that have more than 3 transactions per week for the last year. That means i have to check for 1-1-10 to 7-1-10 to see if someone had more than 3 transactions for that 7 day period, then for 2-1-10 to 8-1-10 then 3-1-10 to 9-1-10 etc etc.
I now i need to use a recursive select but i what i have writen does not produce the correct time frame.
What i have written so far is this

```
WITH Dates AS (
        SELECT
         [Date] = CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/2010')
        UNION ALL SELECT
         [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
        FROM
         Dates
        WHERE
         Date < '12/31/2010'
)

SELECT transaction_person_Id FROM transactions
JOIN DATES
ON transactions.transaction_date = dates.date
where transactions.Transaction_Date between dateadd(DAYOFYEAR,-7,dates.date) and dates.date
group by transaction_person_Id
having count(transaction_person_ID) >= 4
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000)
```

Thanks a lot

PS:
in simple words what i need to do is this

```
 select transaction_person_ID from transactions
    where Transaction_Date between '2010-01-01' and '2010-01-07'
    group by transaction_person_Id
    having count(transaction_person_ID) >= 4
```

then

```
 select transaction_person_ID from transactions
    where Transaction_Date between '2010-01-02' and '2010-01-08'
    group by transaction_person_Id
    having count(transaction_person_ID) >= 4
```

.
.
.
.
.
until it goes

```
 select transaction_person_ID from transactions
    where Transaction_Date between '2010-12-25' and '2010-12-31'
    group by transaction_person_Id
    having count(transaction_person_ID) >= 4
```

i need to have the results of these 365 queries

Comment: YOu want 360 different result sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give one result set with person and weeks, rather then 360 results sets

```
WITH Weeks
     AS (
        SELECT
           CONVERT(DATETIME,'01 Jan 2010') AS WeekStartMidnight, 
           CONVERT(DATETIME,'08 Jan 2010') AS WeekEndMidnight
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
           DATEADD(day, 1, WeekStartMidnight),
           DATEADD(day, 1, WeekEndMidnight)
        FROM
            Weeks
        WHERE
           WeekEndMidnight < '31 Dec 2010'
)
SELECT
   t.transaction_person_Id,
   w.WeekStartMidnight, w.WeekEndMidnight
FROM
   weeks w
   JOIN
   transactions t ON t.Transaction_Date >= w.WeekStartMidnight AND t.Transaction_Date < w.WeekEndMidnight
GROUP BY
   t.transaction_person_Id
HAVING
   count(*) >= 4 --COUNT(t.transaction_person_Id) = same
OPTION
   (MAXRECURSION 365)
```

If you want 360 results sets, it's a loop using WHILE or a CURSOR per row in the "weeks" derived table

Comment: Your answer is 100% right. Just the group by is like this GROUP BY
   t.transaction_person_Id,  w.WeekStartMidnight, w.WeekEndMidnight Thanks a lot